# Menú con library en Code Igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Saludos

Estoy siguiendo un curso de CodeIgniter de Códigofacilito en Youtube y llegué a la parte donde tengo que hacer un menú, el cual no me aparece en pantalla pero a ellos sí.

Aquí va mi carpeta de github con todos mis archivos:

https://github.com/ashcrimson/CodeIgniter

El video es este:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pvl1zucZDoU&index=8&list=PLuaU46Q2O0VojYJHvEahzGgtSIwz9uUD4

El menú está así en mi library:

```
class Menu {
    private $arr_menu;

    public function __construct($arr)
    {
        $this->arr_menu = $arr;
    }
    public function construirMenu() {
        $ret_menu= "<nav><ul>";
        foreach($this->arr_menu as $opcion) {
            $ret_menu .= "<li>".$opcion."</li>";
        }
        $ret_menu= "</ul></nav>";
        return $ret_menu;
    }
}
?>
```

Lo cargo así en el controlador:

```
function index(){
    $this->load->library('menu',array('Inicio', 'Contacto', 'Cursos'));
```

Lo llamo así en la vista:

```
<body>
    <h1>Llamado desde el controlador Código Facilito</h1>
    <?php echo $mi_menu; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

o así:

```
<body>
    <h1>Llamado desde el controlador Código Facilito</h1>
    <?= $mi_menu; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Y no aparece.

¿Qué hice mal? porque a él sí le funciona en el video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la función construirMenu te esta faltando concatenar el ultimo `</ul></nav>` y lo que estas haciendo es asignarle ese valor a la variable $ret_menu, por eso no te va a imprimir nada del menu.

```
public function construirMenu() {
    $ret_menu= "<nav><ul>";
    foreach($this->arr_menu as $opcion) {
        $ret_menu .= "<li>".$opcion."</li>";
    }
    $ret_menu= "</ul></nav>"; //Aquí esta el error
    return $ret_menu;
}
```

La función debería ir:

```
public function construirMenu() {
    $ret_menu= "<nav><ul>";
    foreach($this->arr_menu as $opcion) {
        $ret_menu .= "<li>".$opcion."</li>";
    }
    $ret_menu .= "</ul></nav>"; //Concatena con .=
    return $ret_menu;
}
```

Comment: Era super tonto mi error. Gracias, ahora funciona perfecto.

Comment: De nada, si te fue útil la respuesta marcala como solución a tu problema, así otros usuarios pueden encontrarla útil, y mejoran las estadísticas del sitio.

Comment: Puedes marcarla como solución dándole click al check que esta ubicado debajo del contador de votos de la pregunta.

Comment: Buen día
Una consulta...
Porqué no está seteada la variable "**$mi_menu**" en la vista?
No te trajo algún inconveniente o Error como : "Undefined variable: mi_menu" !??
Un saludo cordial